# Consolidating messy routes in Rails 4. How to organize routes to not point urls to static links?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, code-organization

Here comes a rails nub organizational question:

## What exists:

A "Railsy" link would look something like this (in slim)

```
span
  a href= signout_path
```

`signout_path` correspond to `AuthController#signout`.

So, in my applications there's several types of users - Firefighters, Chiefs and Captains.

Each one has very similar routes:

```
/dashboard
/dashboard/:date
( this is in case they want to see a previous date; 
  same dashboard, different data in the controller )
/account
/account/update
/entry/view
/entry/edit
```

Entries may or may not belong to a user. Because entries should be visible to any user (though not relevant actions)

Take a look at my disgusting mess of routes:

```
scope :firefighters do
    get '/dashboard'        => 'firefighters#dashboard'
    get '/dashboard/:date'  => 'firefighters#dashboard'
    get '/account'          => 'account#account'
    post '/account/update'  => 'firefighters#account_update'

    get '/account/change_password' => 'account#change_password'
    get '/account/change_cell' => 'account#change_cell'
    get '/account/change_email' => 'account#change_email'
    get '/account/change_notifications' => 'account#change_notifications'


    post '/account/update_cell' => 'account#update_cell'

    # post '/account/update_pass' => 'account#update_pass'
    # post '/account/update_cell' => 'account#update_cell'
    # post '/account/update_email' => 'account#update_email'
    # post '/account/update_notifications' => 'account#update_notifications'

    # get '/account/change_cell_number' => 'firefighters#account_change_cell_number'
    # post '/account/request_cell_change' => 'firefighters#account_request_cell_change'
    # post '/account/update_cell' => 'firefighters#account_update_cell'

    # get '/account/change_password' => 'firefighters#account_change_pass'
    # post '/account/update_password' => 'firefighters#account_update_pass'

    # get '/account/change_email' => 'firefighters#account_change_email'
    # post '/account/request_email_change' => 'firefighters#account_request_email_change'
    # post '/account/update_email' => 'firefighters#account_update_email'

    get '/approve'          => 'firefighters#approve'
    get '/set_tester'       => 'firefighters#set_tester'
  end
  scope :entries do
    post '/verify'          => 'entries#verify'
    post '/approve'         => 'entries#approve'
    post '/finalize'        => 'entries#finalize'
    post '/comment'         => 'entries#comment'
    post '/update'          => 'entries#update'
    get '/edit/:entry_id'   => 'entries#edit'
  end
```

I used `scope` to avoid writing a million routes. I moved `Entry` routes under `resources :entries` for this reason.

**Currently, every user type has their own dashboard page with slight variations, just to make it work**

Right now there is a separate `dashboard.slim`, `account.slim`, etc for Firefighters, Chiefs, you get it.

## How I'd like things to be

I'd like to have one dashboard to rule them all. However links like `firefighters_dashboard_path` isn't terribly useful if you only have one view file. I work around this problem by having a slightly different dashboard page for each user. This seems wrong and not at all DRY.

## How do I organize routes so that there is one dashboard and depending on the user, links like `account_path` would lead one to firefighter's account and not an admin's account, for instance?

In other words, I login as captain, the link to my account should be `site.com/account`. I login as manager, my link to management should be 'site.com/managing'. Saving "identity" in session is craziness.

This is a bit to take in, apologies for the wall of text but help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that? Each route maps to one controller action, so you would have `if admin?; elsif firefighter?; else ... end` in every single controller action, plus every view.

You might want to just have a bunch of layouts & partials to share the view code, and leave the route/controller action stuff split up.

Comment: You know you can DRY your code by just having one shared template for dashboard, account, etc. (since you said they mostly are the same for all users). Render those templates manually from controllers `render 'shared/dashboard'`.