# Managing URLs when logged in users change the base of the URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, routes

[Piggybacking off this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36603886/consolidating-messy-routes-in-rails-4-how-to-organize-routes-to-not-point-urls) I asked a second ago, in my app there's sort of a date scroller. Because the url structure goes like `/firefighter/dashboard/11-08-2016` if you want to take a look at that particular date, upon login I actually save the user "type" and so the code for the button looks like this:

```
a.button href="/#{session[:user_type]}/dashboard/#{yesterday}"
```

This seems embarrassing and wrong but with many users sharing many pages all while having different privileges has really thrown me off. I'd like to refactor it so it's not crazy.

The alternative couldn't possibly be making a menu partial for every single user?

Thanks!

Comment: How different are Firefighter, Chief and Captain models? Normally you would have one User model and distinguish between "types" of user via written attributes.

Comment: @PetrGazarov they all inherit from User class, but each of them has individual dashboards, account options and settings, etc. I'm just not sure how to organize routes so that it's not such a mess.

Comment: Alternatively, you can write path helpers for your specific situations. For example, current_user_dashboard_path `link_to 'Link to Dashboard',  current_user_dashboard_path(yesterday)`. Inside the helper you can find who is currently logged in and return the appropriate url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I have understood your question : You are trying to create role specific URLs. 
I usually use [Rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/) gem for maintaining roles and have used its function to find role of that user in my code.

You could do something like this :

1) Assuming you are creating in model User, create a app/libraries/dynamic_router.rb

```
class DynamicRouter
  def self.load
    ComingSoon::Application.routes.draw do
      User.all.each do |pg|
        puts "Routing #{pg.roles.first}"
        get "/dashboard", :to => "#{pg.roles.first}#dashboard", :as => "#{pg.roles.first}_dashboard"
      end
    end
  end

  def self.reload
    ComingSoon::Application.routes_reloader.reload!
  end
end
```

With this you can call dashboard from all your roles like this : 
firefighters_dashboard_path or police_dashboard_path.

2) Let UserController know about your dynamic router :

```
class UserController < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_action :reload_routes

  def reload_routes
    DynamicRouter.reload
  end
end
```

3) To get the dynamic routes generating, the config/routes.rb file was edited to replace the catch-all route with a call on the DynamicRouter.load

```
ComingSoon::Application.routes.draw do
  root 'home#index'
  get 'not_found' => 'users#not_found'
  DynamicRouter.load
end
```

I have taken reference from - http://codeconnoisseur.org/ramblings/creating-dynamic-routes-at-runtime-in-rails-4
You can find more details there.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will answer your question, but if I understand you correctly, you are trying to dry/refactor your routes/controllers.  I'd organize such routes as following:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  POSSIBLE_ROLES = ['firefighter', 'chief', 'captain']
  scope "/:role", defaults: {role: 'firefighter'}, constraints: { role: /#{POSSIBLE_ROLES.join("|")}/ } do
    get "/foo", :to => "controller#action", :as => :foo
  end

end
```

The routes helper would work like this:

```
foo_path # -> /firefighter/foo
foo_path(:role => 'chief') # -> /chief/foo
foo_path(:role => 'something') # throws ActionController::UrlGenerationError
```

You could access the current value in your controllers via `params[:role]`, and you can feel certain that only valid values are passed.

*Edit:*

It's probably worth to mention, that calling an url like `/something/foo` would also result in a routing error (404).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make two assumptions. If these aren't both true, then the advice after probably isn't super useful:

- Your different roles of users have dashboards and other pages that *generally* behave the same
- Where there is variation, it's because some users are capable of certain things other users aren't, and that mostly will amount to some users having extra components visible in views that other users don't.

In this case, I think you would be served well by a simple role & privilege system. A user can have many roles, and each role has many privileges associated with it. As such, a user has a certain set of privileges.

With this in mind, take components of your views that only certain users can use, put those into partials, and wrap the partial in a conditional that checks whether the user has the privilege associated with using that thing. In general, I recommend checking whether a user has a specific privilege as much as possible; that way you are free to change up the privileges associated with roles without worrying that you are breaking a ton of logic in other places.

If there are certain controller actions that should have limited access, you can use a `before_action` method to verify that the user has the correct privilege before you proceed.

An approach like this can help keep your routes file clean and your controllers and views free of unnecessary duplication.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation Single Responsibility Principle is better than DRY.
Use namespaces in routes and different interfaces for each role.

```
namespace :firefighter do
  resource :dashboard, only: :show, controller: :dashboard
end
namespace :chefs do
end
```

Similar parts in views you can move to partials "app/views/shared". Date use as a parameter and don't use in routes.
Code will be more understandable than with dynamic routes.